# How to update a mat table which has dynamic data

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have been trying to create a table which receives dynamic data, when I tried to update the data Its not updating it properly

```
{
  "MAIN": "",
  "tempDetails": {
    "Data1": 10,
    "Data2": 10,
    "Data3": 10,
    "Data4": 10
  }
}
```

this is how the data format would be and in some cases there might be only three data or two data based on the input I need to update the table .

Comment: Please share your code.